# How do I implement app_offline.htm correctly?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an empty site that I use for online purposes. It is essentially just the `app_offline.htm`, an image and a `web.config`. This is running in IIS7.5 with .NET4/Integrated (there's no code, but why not go with the latest?)

When I go to the home page, I get the contents of `app_offline`, but when I go to http://www.contoso.com/about, I get a 404. That problem is solved, per http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/app_offlinehtm-gotchas-with-aspnet-mvc, with

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

But then the image, our logo, stops appearing as well. Is there a way to get the `app_offline.htm` to show up for all friendly URLs, but not for images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encode you image as base64:

```
<img alt="sample" src="data:image/png;base64,ImageToBASE64String"/>
```

app_offline.htm needs to be at least 512 bytes long.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Similar question:
[App_offline.htm, CSS, images, and aspnet_isapi.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602085/app-offline-htm-css-images-and-aspnet-isapi-dll)